# Using sed to replace xml attribute

Tags: xml, sed

My file contains a line like this:

```
<virtual-server name="default-host" enable-welcome-root="false">
```

I want to replace:
 enable-welcome-root from false to true

Using `sed -n 's/.*enable-welcome-root="\([^"]*\).*/\1/p' file`
 I can get the value which is `false`, but how can I replace it?

Comment: You are back reference to wrong group `false`, not to `enable-welcome-root`

Comment: The mandatory "don't parse xml with regular expressions" link: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/7552

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This would change from  `false` or  `true` to  `true`

```
sed -r 's/(enable-welcome-root=")[^"]+"/\1true"/' file
<virtual-server name="default-host" enable-welcome-root="true">
```

or without `-r`

```
sed 's/\(enable-welcome-root="\)[^"]+"/\1true"/'
<virtual-server name="default-host" enable-welcome-root="false">
```

Use `-i` to write back to file

Answer (score 3):

Your string contains no special characters. Thus:

```
s='<virtual-server name="default-host" enable-welcome-root="false">'
r='<virtual-server name="default-host" enable-welcome-root="true">'
sed -i -e "s/$s/$r/" file
```

Comment: I enjoy that way of separating parts of `sed`: it makes it clearer.

Answer (score 3):

Using [`xmlstarlet`](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/overview.php), and adding a close tag to your line:

```
xmlstarlet ed -O -u '//virtual-server/@enable-welcome-root[.="false"]' -v "true" <<END
<virtual-server name="default-host" enable-welcome-root="false">
</virtual-server>
END
```

```
<virtual-server name="default-host" enable-welcome-root="true">
</virtual-server>
```

Comment: The question is about using sed. Not another promoted tool.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/7552